# Specify EL-expression after site has been created

Tags: jquery, jsf, expression, el

I'm currently creating a week-schedule (representing a company:s available consulting-times) with xhtml/EL/backing bean. By default when my page is created I send a parameter '0' that represents the current week. If I try to send '1' I get the schedule for the upcoming week etc. The expression looks like following:

```
<table id="tableSchedule">
    <c:forEach id="forEachCall" items="#{consultation.getSchema('0')}" var="item">
        <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{item}"></h:outputText>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Where the method getSchema returns a list of strings containing td and tr tags.

Now. My intention was to use jQuery to recognize a buttonclick and delete the content of the table and create a new table, in some way like this:

```
    app = "<c:forEach items='#{consultation.getSchema('"+week+"')}' var='item'>";
    app += "<h:outputText escape='false' value='#{item}'></h:outputText></c:forEach>";
    $("#tableSchedule").html(app);
```

Where the variable week keeps track of how many weeks in the future/past should be displayed.

After a lot of googling I've realized that EL-expressions only can be executed while creating the page. Is there any method I can use to overcome this problem?

Note: this is only a very small part of my code.